# How to access the default class implementations for traits

Tags: scala

In Scala it's possible to create objects by invoking the `apply` methods on the companion objects of some classes (or traits, apparently). For example:

```
List(1, 2, 3)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

Set(1, 2, 3)
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3)

Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)
```

In there, `res0` is an instance of the class [`List`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/List.html).

What about `res1` and `res2` however? There are no concrete `Set` or `Map` classes, just traits, and traits cannot be instantiated. What is their class?

Comment: Same applies to `List`: it's an abstract class and so can't be instantiated directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In these cases, `Set` and `Map` are just the declared types of `res1` and `res2`, respectively. To get the actual types, try this:

```
Set(1, 2, 3).getClass.getCanonicalName
Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b").getClass.getCanonicalName
```

Now you'll see that they aren't just instances of traits `scala.collection.immutable.Set` and `scala.collection.immutable.Map`; they're instances of concrete classes implementing those traits.

If you want to know more about how these classes are created, you can view the source code for [Set](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala) and [Map](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala).